# Unwanted line breaker in generated Moshi JsonAdapter

Tags: android, moshi

I have this dataclass used with Moshi:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SearchResult(
    @field:Json(name = "1. symbol") val symbol: String,
    @field:Json(name = "2. name") val name: String,
    @field:Json(name = "4. region") val region: String,
)
```

When I build my application, I have this `SearchResultJsonAdapter` generated with a line breaker after `4.`. This line breaker make my code not compilable...

```
class SearchResultJsonAdapter(
  moshi: Moshi
) : JsonAdapter<SearchResult>() {
  private val options: JsonReader.Options = JsonReader.Options.of("1. symbol", "2. name", "4.
      region")
```

[image]

What can I do to disable line breaking in my JSonAdapter. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue fix after 1.9.3. Using version 1.11.0 in gradle's app helps me to fix this problem:

```
kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.11.0'
```